# If $E(Y\mid X) = a + bX$, what is $E(XY)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables, and $E(Y\mid X) = a + bX$ for some constants $a$, $b$.
What is $E(XY)$?

Here is what I have tried:

$Y E(Y\mid X) = aY + bXY$
$\implies  E(YE(Y|X)) = aE(Y) + bE(XY) = a\mu_y + bE(XY)$
$\implies  E(XY) = (E(YE(Y|X)) - a\mu_y) / b$

But I have no idea how to deal with $E(YE(Y\mid X))$.

Very Thanks!

Comment: The two answers give $aE[X]+bE[X^{2}]$.  I think this is also $E[X]E[Y]+b\mathrm {Var}(X)$

Comment: @Henry Can you provide your solution? Thanks!

Comment: $aE(X)+bE(X^2) = aE(X)+bE(X)^2 +bE(X^2) -bE(X)^2 $ $= E(X)(a+bE[X])+bVar(X) $ $=E(X)E(Y)+bVar(X) $

Comment: Oh I see. This is indeed another solution. Very thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me neither. I recommend using the law of total expectation (essentially, multiply by $X$ and not by $Y$):

$$E(XY)=E(E(XY\vert X))=E(XE(Y\vert X))=E(aX+bX^2)=aE(X)+bE(X^2)$$

Comment: Very thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

You should multiply by $X$ instead of $Y$. We have $XE(Y|X)=aX+bX^{2}$. But $XE(Y|X)=E(XY|X)$ so we get $E(XY|X)=aX+bX^{2}$. Taking expectation on both sides we get $EXY=aEX+bEX^{2}$.

Comment: Very thanks for your solution. Sadly I can only accept one answer so I accept YJT's just because he is slightly faster.